# 8 logical cpu's should give *8 run time benefit?

Tags: node.js

the code i am running when using promise.all should run at about \8 the time when i am using regular "blocking" for, but the result is very similar not even half the time.

i have tried to run this 2 NODEJS programs in the same computer.

WHEN USING PROMISE.ALL

```
let user = { "name": "shay", "interests": ["category1", "category2", "category3", "category4", "category5", "category6", "category7", "category8", "category9", "category10"] }
let result = [];

let Companies = [];
for (i = 0; i < 3000000; i++) {
    let company = { "name": "company" + i, "interest": "category" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1) };
    Companies.push(company);
}

const successRate = () => {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1) + "%"
}

const task = function (interest) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Companies.forEach(company => {
            if (company.interest == interest)
                result.push({ "company": company.name, "interest": company.interest, "success": successRate() })
        });
        resolve('succeed!');
    });
};

const run = async function () {
    let tasks = user.interests.map(interest => {
        return task(interest)
    });
    await Promise.all(tasks);
}
const start = Date.now();
run();
```

WHEN USING REGULAR FOR

```
let user = {"name":"shay","interests":["category1","category2","category3","category4","category5","category6","category7","category8","category9","category10"]}
let result =[];

let Companies = [];
for (i=0;i<3000000;i++)
{
    let company = {"name":"company"+i,"interest":"category"+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1)};
    Companies.push(company);
}

const successRate=()=>{
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1)+"%"
}

const start = Date.now();

user.interests.forEach(interest => {
    Companies.forEach(company => {
        if (company.interest==interest)
            result.push({"company":company.name,"interest":company.interest,"success":successRate()})
    });
});

console.log("run time",Date.now()-start);
```

the promise.all total run time is 1314
the regular for total run time is 1430

Comment: So what's your question actually?

Comment: You have no input / ouput, using promise will change nothing. It will be less efficient as it will run more code than a standard for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js follows a single threaded architecture, it doesn't create a new thread for a new promise - everything runs in the same thread. Asynchronous  behaviour is achieved via event loop, underlying OS concurrency and libuv. If you're familiar with Nginx - it actually works pretty much the same way. So don't mix JavaScript's Promise<> with Java's Future<>.

Comment: so basically what you are saying is that there is no benefits using async functions in functions that are doing some calculation, but only when doing some network stuff (like querying db) or os-tasks (like fs etc..) ?

Comment: Yes, Node.js until today was not suitable for cpu intensive calculations. For this particular reason they released worker threads, which enables essentially multithreading in Node.js environment. I suggest you to have a look on them.